# What were the units of measure used before the metric system was implemented?

Tags: word-choice

As the metric system has not been used for an extremely long period of time, there must have been some type of standardized system in place prior to its use. Thank you.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_units_of_measurement

Comment: For the record, I marked this as "too broad."

Comment: Before asking this sort of question, please consider doing some basic research yourself.  If you've looked it up and still have questions, tell us in your post what you've found and why it doesn't solve your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's all described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_units_of_measurement

Although these are now essentially never used for any sort of calculation, many traces remain in everyday life; the cost of land is quoted in yen per tsubo (坪単価), sake is sold in bottles of 1 *shō* (一升瓶). And my favourite: the staging used to build a platform on stage comes in modular sizes, such as 3x6 or 4x6 *shaku*, always referred to as *saburoku* (3尺x6尺), *shiburoku* (4x6), etc, but the preprinted plan they give you is marked in 1-metre squares.